# Overlay png image with transparent regions on another image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a set of 450 jpg images, each approximately 1200x1500 pixels. I want to apply a black border to every image to make them all 1500x1500 pixels.

Here is an example image: [test01.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkDFW.jpg)
And I want to turn it into as image that looks like this: [1500x1500 image with border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkbl0.png)

The way I have been trying to do it is by superimposing a png image of a [black border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSY5M.png) on top of the original image. However, this hasn't worked very well :( Here's my code so far:

```
A = imread('test01.jpg'); %open image
A2 = imresize(A,[1500 1200]); %resize image to 1500 x 1200 just to make sure it is correct height
RA = imref2d(size(A2));
B = imread('cropper_and_outline_1500x1500.png'); %open cropper
RB = imref2d(size(B));
C = imfuse(A2,B,'blend','Scaling','joint'); %fuse images
imshow(C)
```

Here's my [current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkHJH.png).
There are a few errors... a) the black border is not opaque, b) transparent colour is set to green not transparent, c) the two images are aligned at the top-left corner but I need them centre aligned.

I have been playing with the alpha level to try and fix the green but I didn't really understand what it meant so didn't get far! I also know this might not be the simplest way to do it so if anyone has any other ideas I would really love to hear them. I am trying to do this in MATLAB because  I already have a script for renaming the files and I would ideally like to combine both into a single script.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Images are RGB, so make your transparent image 3 channel, to make it white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just add black lines to the original image?

```
I = imread(yourfile);
expectedSize = [1500, 1500];

% Add horizontal lines of pixels (if needed)
line1 = zeros(1, size(I, 2));
Im = [repmat(line1, [(expectedSize(1) - size(I, 1))/2, 1, 3]); ... % add lines on top
    I; ...
    repmat(line1, [(expectedSize(1) - size(I, 1))/2, 1, 3])]; % add lines on the bottom

% Add vertical lines of pixels (if needed)
line2 = zeros(size(Im, 1), 1);
Im = [repmat(line2, [1, (expectedSize(2) - size(Im, 2))/2, 3]), ... % add lines to the left
    Im, ....
    repmat(line2, [1, (expectedSize(2) - size(I, 2))/2]), 3]; % add lines to the right
```

Well, this was done assuming that the result of `expectedSize(i) - size(I, i)` is divisible by 2, but you get the idea...

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is great! I had some issues adding the vertical line of pixels and in trying to fix it I landed on this in the end:
`code%crop image to 1470x1176 pixels (height x width)
    resized_img = img(16:1485,163:1338,:); 
    % Add horizontal lines of 15 pixels top and bottom
    line1 = zeros(15, size(resized_img, 2), 3);%create line
    im = [line1; resized_img; line1]; %concatonate above and below image
    % Add vertical lines of 162 pixels left and right
    line2 = zeros(size(im, 1), 162, 3); %create line
    im2 = [line2, im, line2]; %concatonate left and right of im`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the problem with the vertical lines? Also, remember to accept the answer if this solution worked for you.

Comment: The size of line2 was not the same as I. I got a little confused by it because that error should have happened for line1 as well but for some reason it only seemed to happen on the vertical lines. Thought it could be a that I needed the z axis too i.e. line2 = zeros(size(Im, 1), 1, 3) but that didn't fully solve it.

Comment: That's strange, it works fine on my end. Maybe you initialized `line2` with the size of the initial image `I` instead of the already modified one `Im`? In any way, glad you found a solution.